# youtube-dl not able to authenticate from amazon ec2 machine

Tags: authentication, amazon-ec2, youtube-dl

I installed youtube-dl on my local machine using curl as mentioned in the official README [here](https://github.com/rg3/youtube-dl#installation).

```
sudo curl -L https://yt-dl.org/downloads/latest/youtube-dl -o /usr/local/bin/youtube-dl
sudo chmod a+rx /usr/local/bin/youtube-dl
```

**Now when I run below command on my local machine**

```
youtube-dl --cookies cookie.txt https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=x-5V_RS3Q48 -u my_account@gmail.com -p my_pass_word
```

I am able to download the video without any hassle as shown below.

[image]

**But when I try to download the same video on one of my ec2 instances, I get the following exception.**

[image]

The installation procedure on both machine is exactly same, youtube-dl version is exactly same (2017.08.18), python version is same (2.7.6)

The only difference I could figure out is the kernel versions on both machines:

**On My Local:** `Linux-3.19.0-25-generic-x86_64-with-Ubuntu-14.04-trusty`

**On EC2 Instance:** `Linux-3.13.0-74-generic-x86_64-with-Ubuntu-14.04-trusty`

Also the video I am trying to download is **private** and uploaded by same user I am providing credentials of.

One important point to note is that EC2 machine is able to download the video without any trouble if I am not using the username & password (which is only possible for videos that are not private)

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Posting the answer in case someone else is stuck with the similar issue.**

The Issue with the cookies not being generated on server edition Linux OS on ec2 instance provided by AWS.

According to what I learnt recently, we don't have support for firefox browser on these machines (at least by default) and that's why it was failing to create the cookie file.

**Solution**

I created the file locally and set expiry time to 20 years in future and moved that cookie on server ec2 instance and used that cookie to sign in rather than creating one.

Thanks